# Z3 gives a NaN value for my floating point constraint

Tags: z3

Given the following floating point constraint, Z3 produces a abnormal model, in which z is NaN. Obviously, it is not a right solution. Is it a bug? 
BTW. the version of z3 is 4.5.0

```
(declare-const x (_ FP 11 53))
(declare-const y (_ FP 11 53))
(declare-const z (_ FP 11 53))


(assert 
 (and 
  (not (fp.lt x (_ +zero 11 53)))
  (not (fp.lt y (_ +zero 11 53)))
  (not (fp.lt z (_ +zero 11 53)))
  (not (fp.leq (fp.add roundNearestTiesToEven x y) z))
 )
)

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, these are the correct semantics for the operators involved (according to SMT-LIB and according to IEEE-754 as well). The model I get is this:

```
(model 
  (define-fun z () (_ FloatingPoint 11 53)
    (_ NaN 11 53))
  (define-fun y () (_ FloatingPoint 11 53)
    (fp #b0 #b00000000000 #x0000000004000))
  (define-fun x () (_ FloatingPoint 11 53)
    (_ +zero 11 53))
)
```

and indeed `(not (fp.leq (fp.add roundNearestTiesToEven x y) z))` is satisfied, i.e., `x + y` is not less than `NaN`, because nothing is less than `NaN` (all predicates are false for `NaN` inputs).

If this behavior is not desired, we can of course add another constraint to make sure `z` is not a `NaN`:

```
(assert (not (= z (_ NaN 11 53))))
```

and Z3 will then find a model where `y` (and thus `x+y`) is `NaN`.